# Schanuel conjecture and its set theoretic status

Tags: number-theory, set-theory

I have once been told that Schanuel's conjecture (which is a transcendence statement about tuples of complex numbers and their exponentials) is set theoretically absolute, which means that its truth (or falsity) is independent of the set theoretical model (or assumptions), because it is a $\Pi^1_2$ statement. Is this correct?

Comment: (The reference to $\Pi_2$ is imprecise. See my comments on one of the answers.)

Comment: I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an extremely sloppy reference to the Shoenfield absoluteness theorem.

This theorem says that given an arithmetical statement about the natural numbers which is not "too complicated" (first-order statements are not too complicated, but not just them), then the statement is true in every two transitive models of $\sf ZFC$ which have the same ordinals.

This doesn't mean that the truth value is independent of $\sf ZFC$. It just means that we cannot prove independence using the two "usual" tools of set theory:

1. **Forcing**, which does not change the ordinals of a model, nor destroy its transitivity; and
2. **Inner models**, which are by definition a subclass of the model which is transitive and contains all the ordinals.

There might be other ways to prove independence, e.g. compactness arguments of some sort. But things like compactness usually destroy nice properties of models of $\sf ZFC$, and the absoluteness theorem no longer applies. On the other hand, we are less interested in not-nice models of $\sf ZFC$ in general, which is why set theorists focus on the two methods above, rather than other methods.

So the conclusion is that if we can force the truth value of the Schanuel conjecture, then we actually proved it.

Answer (score 8):

You need to be a bit careful how you state it. Remember that Con(ZF) is a $\Pi_1^0$ statement, and that is independent of ZF.

I think what you're looking for is [Shoenfield absoluteness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem). This implies that $\Pi_2^1$ statements are independent of certain axioms that can be added to ZF. Amongst these axioms are the axiom of choice and the generalised continuum hypothesis. Hence if you have a proof of Schanuel's conjecture that assumes choice and CH, then there must be a proof using only the axioms of ZF.

It's also the case that if a $\Pi_2^1$ statement holds, then it also holds in any transitive models of ZF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about Solovay's model: if I have a proof of Schanuel in Solovay model, does it hold also in ZFC?

Comment: I don't really know about Solovay's model, but it looks like it's built as an inner model of a forcing extension, so I think everything should work there.

Comment: You are mixing things here. $\mathrm{CON}(\mathsf{ZF})$ is $\Pi^0_1$, meaning it has the form $\forall n\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is a recursive statement (and $n$ varies over natural numbers). On the other hand, a straightforward translation of the standard formulation of Schanuel's conjecture, is $\Pi^1_2$, meaning it has the form $\forall r\exists y\psi(r,y)$, where $r,y$ vary over real (or complex) numbers, and $\psi$ is an arithmetic statement (meaning, all its quantifiers vary over numbers). (Cont.)

Comment: On the other hand, $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ mean yet something different from these two definitions, and Shoenfield's theorem does not apply to $\Pi_2$ statement. In fact, $\Pi_1$ statements are not absolute.

Comment: Re the Solovay model thing, there is a different problem in this case: To build Solovay's model, you need resources beyond $\mathsf{ZFC}$, on consistency strength grounds. If Schanuel's conjecture is proved in Solovay's model, then it is true, but the proof *may* require the theory $\mathsf{ZFC}+$"There is an inaccessible cardinal".

Comment: (And note that $\mathrm{CON}(\mathsf{ZF})$ is not provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. As with the situation in Solovay's model, absoluteness is different from provability. The other answer also addresses this issue.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'll add the superscripts.

Comment: Another clarification: $1.$ $\mathsf{CH}$ is $\Sigma^2_1$, way beyond the reach of Shoenfield's absoluteness. For reasons that have nothing to do with Shoenfield's result, projective statements (in particular, Schanuel's conjecture) that are provable with $\mathsf{CH}$ are provable without needing this assumption. $2.$ The axiom of choice does not even belong to the hierarchy of $\Pi^n_m$ statements that we have been discussing. [But it is true that thanks to Shoenfield, if a $\Pi^1_2$ statement is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then it is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$.]

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding Shoenfield absoluteness then. I thought it meant that if a $\Pi_2^1$ statement is provable in ZF + V=L, then it is provable in ZF. Is this not the case?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Is there some online reference for these things?

Comment: @aws It does not *mean* that, but it *implies* it. A usual formulation of Shoenfield's absoluteness says that $\Pi^1_2$ statements are absolute between transitive models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ that share the same ordinals. Suppose $\phi$ is $\Pi^1_2$ and provable from choice (or in $\mathsf{ZF}+V=L$, if you wish). Argue in $\mathsf{ZF}$. Since $\phi$ is $\Pi^1_2$, its truth value is absolute between the universe and the inner model $L$. (Cont.)

Comment: @aws But $\phi$ is provable from choice, and choice holds in $L$, so $\phi$ *holds* in $L$ (or, if you rather assume that $\phi$ is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}+V=L$, then we conclude directly that $\phi$ holds in $L$). Absoluteness then gives us that $\phi$ is true in the universe, as we wanted. (So, you see, this is a consequence of Shoenfield's result. But Shoenfield's is stronger, since for example it is not tied up to provability in any particular system.)

Comment: Right, that's all that I was trying to say. I just mentioned GCH and AC as examples of things that hold in L (I certainly didn't mean to imply they were $\Pi_2^1$!). Sorry my writing was unclear.

Comment: (Yes. The thing with $\mathsf{CH}$ is that even if we are in settings incompatible with $V=L$, if $\mathsf{CH}$ proves a projective statement, then the statement is provable without it. The point is that we can always extend the universe without adding reals, and obtain a model of $\mathsf{CH}$. But since no reals were added, the projective theory does not change.)